# Opening a user uploaded PDF in django

Tags: python, django

I have a webapp where a user can upload a pdf file. I want the user to be able to click a button to be able to see the file in the browser.

I'm not sure how to link the pdfs as when they are uploaded they get given a random name by django in my static root. eg: hello_0akcjs.pdf

**My View**

```
def pdf_view(request, pk):
    Menufile = Menu.objects.get(pk=pk).menuFile
    with open('Menufile', 'r') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
    return response
```

**URL**

```
path('<int:pk>/', pdf_view, name='pdf_view'),
```

**Model**

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuFile = models.FileField(upload_to='menus')
```

**Template**

```
{% for menu in menus %}

<a href="{% url 'pdf_view' menu.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">View Menu {{ menu.name }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

As it stands, everything works, except i just dont know how to get the pdf to be rendered at the URL for that model instances PK.

Answer (score 1):

I was making it far too complicated. All i needed to do was reference the menuFile URL in the template.

Example:

```
<a href="{{ menu.menuFile.url }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="margin: 2px;">View Menu</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a pdf you have to use an embed tag,

```
<embed src={% url 'pdf_view'  menu.pk %} width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">
```